# ReCaptcha "incorrect-captcha-sol" error showing up on page load

Tags: php, validation, recaptcha

Okay my contact form (http://jshjohnson.com/new/contact.php) works as it should however the ReCaptcha error (that usually comes up when you enter the words incorrectly) shows up on page load.

I have set an empty variable called message which should stop this but it unfortunately doesn't.

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
require_once('recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "6LdLX9oSAAAAALZawj-uldWrjsI0zYcR-w_r_sNh";
$privatekey = "<removed>";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
$recaptcha_form = recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
$message = "";

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
$message = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.
(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")";
} else {
// ADD YOUR CODE HERE to handle a successful ReCAPTCHA submission
// e.g. Validate the data

$myemail  = "contact@jshjohnson.com";
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$fullname = $firstname . " " . $surname;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['message'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$subject = "Website Contact";



if($firstname == '') {
    $message = 'Please type your first name' ;
} else if ($surname == '') {
        $message = 'Please type your surname';
    } else if ($email == '') {
        $message = 'Please type your email';

        if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/", $email)) {
            $message = "Email address is valid";
        } else {
            $message = "Email address is invalid";
        }
    } else if ($contact == '') {
        $message = 'Please type your message';

    } else {

    /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
    $contact = "Hello!

 Josh Johnson Web Design contact form has been submitted by:

 Name:* $fullname 
 E-mail:* $email
 Website: $website
 Budget: £

 Message:*
  $contact

 End of message
  ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $contact);

    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
  }
 ?>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: I would remove your private key - you're not supposed to give it out

Comment: @jshjohnson It's still in the edit history: "6LdLX9oSAAAAAHHHaxAd0PkR6yKyqgOR-8Bec-la". You have to totally get a new key now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete or ignore that errors. In Rails, it is

```
  flash[:recaptcha_error] = nil
```

For your PHP, you always check if it's valid with

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
```

and then print the error with `$resp->error`. So even if nothing was typed in yet on first page load, it might think it is invalid and print the error. Instead, check to see if the  `recaptcha_response_field` is empty or not before verifying the CAPTCHA.